# Failed to acquire connection <Connection Name> If Transaction is enabled

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS Package I have a sequence container and I have enabled **TransactionOption - Required**. Within the container I have a execute SQL task that make use of a ADO.Net Connection to SQL Server.

The package throws **[Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection . Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection**.

I face this error only if I set TransactionOption as Required. Another information if I point my ADO.Net connection to my local SQL server it runs perfectly but If I point to the Server then I face this issue.

The Isolation level is Serializable. The Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is running on the local machine as well as server machine.

Please let me know if you require additional details. Thanks in advance

Any idea? Please...

Comment: Going with the obvious, do you have permissions to create explicit transactions? I recall when we were using DB2 as a source, we'd have to have an explicit permission for transactions assigned to our account

Comment: Using SA account so I believe I have permission.

Comment: SA on the box the ETL is running on or SA on the machine at the end of your ADO.NET connection?

Comment: It is SA on both machines. Also the package fails even while I run from the BIDS window pointing to the Server(SA login). I also tried deploying to file system and then added the package as a job in the local SQL Server Agent (SA Login) it threw the same error message.

Comment: Any idea please ... I can see it work on one database (local db) but not on server, is there any server specific requirement? It does not connect to the database only with in a transaction in other sections it still works.

Comment: Does this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924.aspx